# Having trouble aligning checkboxes in an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, text-align

I can't get the `checkboxes` in the first column of my `table` to be aligned on the right.

```
<form>
   <div>    
        <table>
            <th>Trail</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Mileage</th>
            <th>Direction</th>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="AT">AT</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="AT" name="AT"  value="Yes">
                </td>
```

I'm using the `CSS` code of:

```
input [type=checkbox] {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: my answer should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

what about trying this

```
<table>
    <th>Trail</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Mileage</th>
    <th>Direction</th>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="AT" name="AT"  value="Yes"/>
            <label for="AT">AT</label>
        </td>
```

here is the [jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0xefu5w/)

Comment: So simple.  I was over thinking it.  Looks better with the checkbox first too.  Thanks.